# OpenGL ignores Quads and makes them Triangles

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

This is the second time I'm making a game engine, but I'm a little stuck right now, since I cannot figure out why this is happening, no matter what object I send, OpenGL only draws a White Triangle on the center of the screen, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkF1a.png)

I've even coppied my old code from my last engine on the Renderer and the Camera Objects, still acts the same, so I´m guessing it has something to do with the Render Script.

Renderer:

```
Renderer2D::Renderer2D(const Shader& shader) {
    this->shader = shader;
    this->Init();
}

Renderer2D::~Renderer2D() {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->QuadVAO);
}

void Renderer2D::Render(Texture & texture, iVec2 position, iVec2 size, float rotation, iVec3 color) {
    this->shader.Use();
    iMat4 model;

    using namespace glm;
    model = translate(model, iVec3(position.x, position.y, 0.0f));
    /*
    model = translate(model, iVec3(size.x * 0.5f, size.y * 0.5f, 0.0f));
    model = rotate(model, rotation, iVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    model = translate(model, iVec3(size.x * -0.5f, size.y * -0.5f, 0.0f));
    */
    model = glm::scale(model, iVec3(size.x, size.y, 1.0f));

    this->shader.SetMatrix4("model2D", model);
    this->shader.SetVector3f("color2D", color);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.Bind();

    glBindVertexArray(this->QuadVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Renderer2D::Init() {
    U16 VBO;

    float vertices[] = {
        // Pos      // Tex
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->QuadVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(this->QuadVAO);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 position, vec2 texCoords>

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 view2D;
uniform mat4 model2D;
uniform mat4 projection2D;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
    gl_Position = projection2D * view2D * mode2Dl * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 position, vec2 texCoords>

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 view2D;
uniform mat4 model2D;
uniform mat4 projection2D;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
    gl_Position = projection2D * view2D * model2D * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color2D; //Fixed the error!

uniform sampler2D image2D;
uniform vec3 color2D;

void main()
{    
    color2D = vec4(color2D, 1.0) * texture(image2D, TexCoords);
}
```

Resources.cpp

```
Shader Resources::LoadShaderFromFile(const char * vertexSource, const char * fragmentSource) {
    using namespace std;
    string vertexCode;
    string fragmentCode;

    try {
        ifstream vertexShaderFile(vertexSource);
        ifstream fragmentShaderFile(fragmentSource);
        stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;

        vShaderStream << vertexShaderFile.rdbuf();
        fShaderStream << fragmentShaderFile.rdbuf();

        vertexShaderFile.close();
        fragmentShaderFile.close();

        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
    }
    catch (exception e) {
        cout << "ERROR::SHADER: Failed to read shader files" << std::endl;
    }

    const char *vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
    const char *fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

    Shader shader;
    shader.Compile(vShaderCode, fShaderCode);

    return shader;
}
```

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you running? Are you aware that as of OpenGL 3+ quads are deprecated?

Comment: @Patrick I just added Quads on the title because I´m trying to draw quads, but I´m Actually drawing 2 triangles next to each other, just updated the question with that code.

Comment: Could you try changing the z coordinates of the triangles to -1.0f instead of 0.0f. I believe the triangle is clipping since positive z is out of screen.

Comment: @Patrick  `model = translate(model, iVec3(position.x, position.y, -1.0f)); ` Changed this line, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Patrick I'm starting to think is a view port error or something since, no matter what coordinates I enter, triangle will always be the same position with no texture.

Comment: No in your vertex array try changing the z values to zero. I just realised I said `-1.0f instead of 0.0f` I meant to say -1.0f instead of 1.0f.

Comment: @Patrick It just flipped the triangle to the down left side of the screen, that meaning it's compleately ignoring the position sent. It only follows the vertices coordinates and only makes 1 triangle! Still have no idea how to solve it... Also, it totally ignores the indices 7 to 12 on the vertices array...

Comment: Seems like some sort of transform is being applied incorrectly try setting all transform matrices to identity matrix (glm::mat4(1.0f))

Comment: How should I do that? Sorry I still don't get glm that well...

Comment: Also if I may ask: why are you using imat4 for your model matrix? Are you only transforming by integral amounts or something?

Comment: Just set model to `glm::mat4(1.0f)` also try using floating point matrix `glm::mat4` instead of integer matrix `imat4`

Comment: is just my naming convention, its a `#define` for `glm::mat4`

Comment: Nothing changed when I made ` model = glm::mat4(1.0f);`

Comment: Ohh I think I may see the problem. It looks like your interleaving vertex and uv data but you define in `glVertexAttribPointer` call that the vertex buffer has four components per attribute, try changing second argument to 2 instead of 4.

Comment: @Patrick Well, that's something, at least it renders the full quare now, but still no texture and not the desired position!

Comment: Could you post your shader code its hard to tell the problem without it

Comment: Also you aren't rendering texture properly because you aren't sending uv coords to gpu anymore. Your options are to send a vec4 which has xy as vertex coords and zw as uv coords or you could create a new buffer for uv data.

Comment: @Patrick Just Posted the Vertex and Fragment code, not sure what you mean with I'm not sending the uv coords anymore tho...

Comment: If you use a size of 2 for glVertexAttribPointer then you'll be missing the uv components, but it looks like you aren't doing that... I would suggest debugging texture data, format and binding in your Texture class if your not seeing the texture. **Edit:** I just noticed that you are multiplying fragment color by sprite color why are you doing this? is this a dot product? Try just using `color = texture(image, TexCoords)`

Comment: I'll try that, but what about the position and the size being incorrect? Is it because of the shader? It just takes the normal vertices position

Comment: The original size of 4 should work with your shader.

Comment: Then why isn’t it resizing? Does it have to do with the texture error?

Comment: Why isn't what resizing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'r shader doesn't even compile. When you declare the matrix uniforms, then you use the names `model2D`, `view2D` and `projection2D`:

```
uniform mat4 view2D;
uniform mat4 model2D;
uniform mat4 projection2D;
```

But when you use the matrices, then you use the names `view`, `model` and `projection`:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
```

---

I recommend to check if the shader objects compiled successfully and if the program object link successfully.

If the compiling of a shader succeeded can be checked by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`.

e.g.

```
GLuint shaderObj = .... ;
glCompileShader( shaderObj );

GLint status = GL_TRUE;
glGetShaderiv( shaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
if ( status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint logLen;
    glGetShaderiv( shaderObj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
    std::vector< char >log( logLen );
    GLsizei written;
    glGetShaderInfoLog( shaderObj, logLen, &written, log.data() );
    std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

If the linking of a program was successful can be checked by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_LINK_STATUS`.

e.g.

```
GLuint progObj = ....;
glLinkProgram( progObj );

GLint status = GL_TRUE;
glGetProgramiv( progObj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
if ( status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint logLen;
    glGetProgramiv( progObj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
    std::vector< char >log( logLen );
    GLsizei written;
    glGetProgramInfoLog( progObj, logLen, &written, log.data() );
    std::cout  << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: got the following error, link error:
Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position.

Comment: Just Updated the code with the Resources.cpp but I think there is no error while loading the shader.

Comment: @MarceloColonia Ther is a typo in your code: `mode2Dl` instead of `model2D`

Comment: sorry that typo is because I manually wrote the update instead of copying it, the original code is correct.

Comment: @MarceloColonia You got a link error, possibly you swapped the vertex and the fragment shader or you didn't proper load the shaders form the file and the source code strings are empty.

Comment: already checked, sources are fine, but I have detected an error on texture loading, could it have any effect on that error message at all?

Comment: Thanks, I found out there was actually an error on fragment shader, I was exporting color instead of color2D, it works now.