# How to draw a VAO made out of 5 triangles in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, gl-triangle-strip

I have recently written a program to draw a triangle with 3 different RGB values and I want to do the same with another separate VAO in the same program but I want this one composed of 5 triangles. Here is my main.cpp:

```cpp
void framebuffer_size_callback(GFLWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// Shaders
const char *vertexShaderSource =
"#version 410\n"
"in vec3 vp;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";

const char *fragmentShader1Source =
"#version 410\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec3 myColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"FragColor = vec4(myColor, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main ()
{
// start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
if (!glfwInit ())
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
    return 1;
    }
    // uncomment these lines if on Apple OS X
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);

    printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    /* OTHER STUFF GOES HERE */

    // Draw a single triangle VBO
    float points[] = {
    // positions       // colors
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate a VAO.
    GLuint VAO = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Compile a Vertex Shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Compile a fragment shader.
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Compile shaders into a executable shader program.
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Drawing the triangles aka render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);
        // wipe the drawing surface clear
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw Triangle
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        // Draw Triangle Fan; unfinished

        // swap buffers and poll IO events
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Do I simply create another float "points" matrix like I did with my first VBO or something else? The tutorial Im following wasn't perfectly clear on this part.

Also, Im using Xcode on my Mac and I created separate .cpp files for my Fragment and Vertex shaders. Should I switch those to header files instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify an input attribute for the color (`aColor`) and to pass the color attribute from the vertex shader to the fragment shader (`myColor`). Use [Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) to specify the attribute indices.

```c
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 myColor;

void main()
{
    myColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

```cpp
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 myColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(myColor, 1.0f);
}
```

Note your current vertex shader does not compile. Check if compiling of a shader succeeded checked by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` and if the linking of a program was successful can be checked by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_LINK_STATUS`. See the answer to [OpenGL ignores Quads and makes them Triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218925/opengl-ignores-quads-and-makes-them-triangles/53220726#53220726) for some code snippets.

---

Your vertices are tuples with 6 components (x, y, z, r, g, b):

> ```c
> float points[] = {
>     // positions       // colors
>     0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
>     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
>    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f 0.0f, 1.0f
> };
> ```

Use [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) to specify 2 vertex attributes. The stride and the offset have to be specified in bytes. The stride is `6 * sizeof(float)`. The offset of the vertex coordinates is 0 and the offset of the color attributes is `3 * sizeof(float)`. e.g:

```c
GLuint VBO = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Generate a VAO.
GLuint VAO = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), NULL);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
```

---

If you want to draw more complex meshes, then you have to extend the vertes arrays. Just add another 3 vertices and colors to `points` array for the next triangle. Alternatively you can use a different primitive type like `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. See [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)

Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Shaders
const char *vertexShaderSource = R"(#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 myColor;

void main()
{
    myColor = aColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
)";

const char *fragmentShaderSource = R"(#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 myColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(myColor, 1.0f);
}
)";

bool CompileStatus( GLuint shader );
bool LinkStatus( GLuint program );

float radians( float deg ) { return deg * 3.141529 / 180.0; }

int main ()
{
    // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // uncomment these lines if on Apple OS X
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);

    printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    /* OTHER STUFF GOES HERE */

    // Draw a single triangle VBO
    float points[] = {
        // positions                                         // colors
        0.0f,                     0.0f,                      0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,                     0.0f,                      0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f * cos(radians(72)),  0.5f * sin(radians(72)),   0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f * cos(radians(144)), 0.5f * sin(radians(144)),  0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f * cos(radians(216)), 0.5f * sin(radians(216)),  0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f * cos(radians(288)), 0.5f * sin(radians(288)),  0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5,                      0.0f,                      0.0f,   1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint VBO = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate a VAO.
    GLuint VAO = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), NULL);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));

    // Compile a Vertex Shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    CompileStatus( vertexShader );

    // Compile a fragment shader.
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    CompileStatus( fragmentShader );

    // Compile shaders into a executable shader program.
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    LinkStatus( shaderProgram );

    // Drawing the triangles aka render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //processInput(window);
        // wipe the drawing surface clear
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw Triangle
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 7);

        // Draw Triangle Fan; unfinished

        // swap buffers and poll IO events
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

bool CompileStatus( GLuint shader )
{
    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
        std::vector< char >log( logLen );
        GLsizei written;
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logLen, &written, log.data() );
        std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return status != GL_FALSE;
}

bool LinkStatus( GLuint program )
{
    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
        std::vector< char >log( logLen );
        GLsizei written;
        glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logLen, &written, log.data() );
        std::cout << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return status != GL_FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right and this is a very robust answer

Comment: @NathanWride Please correct the shader and the vertex specification in your answer. It would confuse other users.

Comment: I actually feel that the poster should change the accepted answer, if not then I'll append your recommendations in the morning for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by adding creating another float array containing your new points, and creating another VAO and VBO. Since you want a **triangle fan** (based on the comment in your code), and not 5 individual triangles you would make it like this:

```
float points_5_triangles[] = {
    // positions       // colors
    // Original triangle
    x1, y1, z1, r1, g1, b1,    // point 1
    x2, y2, z2, r2, g2, b2,    // point 2
    x3, y3, z3, r3, g3, b3,    // point 3
    // Another triangle made from point 1, 3 and 4
    x4, y4, z4, r4, g4, b4,
    // Another triangle made from point 1, 4 and 5
    x5, y5, z5, r5, g5, b5,
    // Another triangle made from point 1, 5 and 6
    x6, y6, z6, r6, g6, b6,
    // Another triangle made from point 1, 6 and 7
    x7, y7, z7, r7, g7, b7,
};

GLuint VBO_5_triangles = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_5_triangles);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_5_triangles);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points_5_triangles), points_5_triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Generate another VAO.
GLuint VAO_5_triangles = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO_5_triangles);
glBindVertexArray(VAO_5_triangles);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_5_triangles);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points_5_triangles), points_5_triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Now when drawing your two objects you would first bind the target VAO, then render, then carry on to the next object:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glBindVertexArray(VAO_5_triangles);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 7);
```

For more information on how a triangle fan is drawn see [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)

Comment: Ok so the x1, y1, z1 and so on represent float numbers correct? Also, the comments say to make another triangle from points 1, 3, and 4 but there are only 3 original points. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Sorry, but do you not see that vertex attribute specification doesn't match the the array of vertices and colors? Do you see that the vertex shader fails to compile? And that there is no vertex shader output for the  the fragment shader input `myColor`?

Comment: @Garrus each line in the float array makes 1 point from 3 floats for position and 3 floats for colour. Triangle fans are a special form of triangles that use the first entry as the root point and then makes a triangle with the root and every following pair (i.e 1,2,3 1,3,4, 1,4,5 etc. You should read the link for more detail and helpful diagrams. Rabbid76 is absolutely right, but I decided to just address the question asked about adding another object with 5 triangles. I think Garrus should absolutely follow your recommendations as well to fix their shaders.